# Do we need to increment thread-local variable atomically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, thread-safety, atomic

Below is a function from LLVM's libcxxabi:

```
void *__cxa_current_primary_exception() throw() {
    //  get the current exception
    __cxa_eh_globals* globals = __cxa_get_globals_fast();
    if (NULL == globals)
        return NULL;        //  If there are no globals, there is no exception
    __cxa_exception* exception_header = globals->caughtExceptions;
    if (NULL == exception_header)
        return NULL;        //  No current exception
    if (!isOurExceptionClass(&exception_header->unwindHeader))
        return NULL;        // Can't capture a foreign exception (no way to refcount it)
    if (isDependentException(&exception_header->unwindHeader)) {
        __cxa_dependent_exception* dep_exception_header =
        reinterpret_cast<__cxa_dependent_exception*>(exception_header);
        exception_header = cxa_exception_from_thrown_object(dep_exception_header->primaryException);
    }
    void* thrown_object = thrown_object_from_cxa_exception(exception_header);
    __cxa_increment_exception_refcount(thrown_object);
    return thrown_object;
}
```

globals is a thread-local storage variable, and therefore the thrown_object is also specific for a thread. My understanding is that thrown_object is an exception thrown in a thread - each thread may throw its own exception.

But the function __cxa_increment_exception_refcount() performs increment atomically - why? What's the scenario that requires increment to be performed atomically?

Comment: Re, "globals is a thread-local...and therefore the `thrown_object` is also specific for a thread." I don't know LLVM's run-time support libraries, and I don't know whether or not `*thrown_object` could be shared with other threads, but you can't tell just from looking at the code sample above. The `__cxa_current_primary_exception()` function finds `*thrown_object` by following a chain of pointers, and just because `globals` itself is a thread local variable, that doesn't prove that the object it points to is not shared, and it doesn't prove anything about other objects further along the chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) and get a smart-pointer to the exception:

> `std::exception_ptr` is a nullable pointer-like type that manages an exception object which has been thrown and captured with std::current_exception. **An instance of `std::exception_ptr` may be passed to another function, possibly on another thread**, where the exception may be rethrown and handled with a catch clause.
>
> ...
>
> `std::exception_ptr` is a shared-ownership smart pointer.

Because `std::exception_ptr` can be passed to another thread the reference counter maintenance must use atomic increment/decrement.

The reference counter is embedded into the exception object, like for `boost::intrusive_ptr` and unlike `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't get when we need atomic increment. Let's suppose that we caught an exception in a worker-thread and saved it in a global std::exception_ptr - do we need atomical increment in this scenario? Let's further suppose that we're passing saved global exception_ptr into another thread - do we need atomic increment now?

Comment: @embedc In case when _we caught an exception in a worker-thread and saved it in a global `std::exception_ptr`_ the worker thread may have a local copy that gets eventually destroyed and another thread may make another copy of the global one, simultaneously incrementing and decrementing the same reference counter. This is why the reference counter must be thread safe.